# How to solve this error Using org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser Exception

Tags: html

Hi I am trying to run some diagnostics on my semantics and i keep running into this error  when i look on http://www.w3.org/2003/12/semantic-extractor.html 
my site is [www.bolderentertainment.com](http://www.bolderentertainment.com/) any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Using org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
Exception net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "html" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</html>". 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "html" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</html>".
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an unclosed `<html>` tag somewhere in the string. Close it and the error will go away.

```
<html>
  <div>
    <!-- contents and other tags -->
  </div>
</html> <!--  You don't have this closing tag -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making your page [validate as correct HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bolderentertainment.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) first.

Among the various things you need to fix:

- `<script>` tags need to be inside either the `<head>` or the `<body>` tags.
- `<p>` tags need to be inside the `<body>` tags.
- You have two `<noframes>` sections that are redundant.